# Question about Borel sigma algebra

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a question regarding singletons (unit set) in a Borel-sigma algebra:

Lets say that K is a σ-algebra on a random range [0,100]:

A. Is it true that i can take any singleton in this range [0,100] , lets take for example {5}
and claim that it is an event in the Borel σ-algebra - k  ?

B. If my previous question ('A') is indeed true, does it follow from the next explanation:
we can consider the decreasing sequence of events (a-1/n,a+1/n) where n goes to infinity.
Since any σ-algebra is closed under intersections of countable number of events we get that $\lim_{n->infinity} (a-1/n,a+1/n)$=a is in the σ-algebra, which in out case is 'K'.
Where in our case we would have take 'a' to be 5.
*Please correct me if i am wrong with the assumption that the last sequence of events is countable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cap_{n=1}^\infty [0,1/n] = \{0\}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cap_{n=1}^\infty [100-1/n,100] = \{100\}$

For $a \neq 0,100$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cap_{n=1}^\infty [a-1/n,a+1/n] = \{a\}$

Thus, all singletons are contained in $K$. Note that all $[a,b]$ where $0\leq a \leq b \leq 100$ are in the Borel sigma algebra to begin with.

A simpler explanation is that the Borel sigma algebra is the one generated by all open sets. Since sigma algebras are closed under complements, the Borel sigma algebra also contains all closed set, since a set is closed if and only if its complement is open. Singletons are closed sets (in a T1 space, which every metric space is). It is easy to write the singleton as a complement of the open set $((-1,a)\cap [0,100])\cup (a,101) \cap [0,100])$ which is open, since it is the union of two open sets in $[0,100]$.

Comment: Thx, it helped me understand the Borel sigma algebras a bit better. 

And just another thought, a 'yes' will suffice if it is true:
Since sigma-algebras are closed under intersections we can get sets which are not continuous by lets say, take the complement of (14,15) and get the set [0,14]Union[15,100].

Comment: By continuous, you presumably mean connected (which in $\mathbb{R}$ means intervals). And the answer is "Of course". Your Borel sigma algebra contains the Cantor set, for example. Or the rational numbers between 0 and 100 inclusive. There are many examples (in fact, "most" of the Borel sets are not nice ones you'd think of off the top of your head - even the open sets, which generate the Borel sigma algebra, are not all intervals (though they can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals)).